# O que significa esse -j8?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, linux

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu to aprendendo a configurar um servidor e me deparei com esse comando -j8. Eu não encontrei em lugar nenhum uma explicação do porque esse comando. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o que ele faz? Obrigado desde já

Comment: Que tal: `$ man make`

Comment: Aqui diz tudo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15289250/1377664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `-j8` é um parâmetro passado pro compilador para utilizar 8 núcleos do processador durante a compilação, para agilizar o processo.

Para dúvidas sobre parâmetros de utilidades de linha de comando em geral:
 usar `man <comando>` mostra o manual da utilidade, que é bastante compreensivo para as utilidades mais comuns e em geral resolve qualquer dúvida superficial.